# Git repository migrated from Mercurial shows unnamed branches

Tags: git, mercurial, github, branch

https://github.com/lextm/sharpsnmplib/network

This repository network graph shows lots of branches (were created in Mercurial), but none of them has a name.

Is there a way to add names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git branch branch-name starting-point
```

or

```
git checkout starting-point
git branch branch-name
```

where *starting-point* is the commit ID of the latest commit in that branch. For example, `git br newcompiler 5983450`. (You can use *gitk* or *tig* as a more convenient way to browse the repository than GitHub's graph.)

Git tags can be created in the same way using `git tag`.

---

Migration between VCS systems almost never gives perfect results, so before you continue working on your project, take the chance to clean up the Git repository – it's currently in a messy state; for example, even though the `6.0` tag already exists, it doesn't share *any* commits with the `master` branch, as you could see from `diff -y <(git lg 40130c97) <(git lg 6.0)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It did create all branch names as I wished.